# NestJS - MikroORM how to get id after creation

Tags: nestjs, mikro-orm

I'm using MikroORM in my newest project and I was wondering, is it possible to return the newly created record id?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be available on the entity once you flush:

```
const user = new User();
em.persist(user);
await em.flush();
console.log(user.id);
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I cannot believe that i missed it. Thanks again for your great job with mikro orm